# How can I create a simple python brute force function?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that will use brute force for an academic python project. The password can be limited I want to pass in the password and the function iterate through a set of characters(a-z,A-Z,0-9) trying combinations till the password is found. I know this will be inefficient so for testing lets assume the password is 4 characters long. Any help getting started on writing this function would be appreciated.

Comment: Please for now on show some effort when you ask questions here. Show what you have tried and thought of and what went wrong. The way you phrased your question seems very much like 'please solve my problems because I dont want to'. Not only will the added information make your question easier to answer, but the answers will be of a higher quality because they will focus on the specific things you got wrong

Comment: I tried more not shown here. I din't want to limit answers by my failed attempts that don't work. If you haven't been there don't worry you will get there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement(characters,password_length) #1
for password in gen:                                                      #2 
    check_password(password)                                              #3
```

here's how it works:

- line 1: this creates a generator. it's like a function that remembers where it left off. Check this out for more info: http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/generators.html. This particular generator goes through all possible combinations of the given characters of the given length.
- line 2: for each iteration of the for loop next(gen) is called. This *yields* the next value
- line 3: Do what you need to do

for example if `characters = '01234567890'` and `password_length = 2` then the loop will run through the combinations: `('0','0'), ('0','1'), ('0','2')...('0','9'),('1','0'),('1','1')...('9','9')`.

Comment: itertools.permutations is a better idea. combinations_with_replacement won't reorder them.

Answer (score 0):

For a pre-known length :

```
import random
a_z = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
while password != curtry:
    currenttry = random.choice(a_z)+random.choice(a_z)+random.choice(a_z)+random.choice(a_z)
```

For a random length :

```
import random
a_z = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
while password != curtry:
    leng = random.randint(4,12) #random int between 4 and 12
    i = 0
    curtry = "lol"
    for i<leng:
         curtry += random.choice(a_z)
```